# Find two numbers that have the maximum sum which is also an element in the array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I recently got this question in an interview:

Given an array find two numbers that have the maximum sum which is also an element in the array.

Input: 6 10 12 34 41 16
Output: 16

[Updated]My code below:

```
    public class Solution {
    public static int findMaximumNumbers(int a[])
    {
        Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
        for(int n:a) set.add(n);
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=a.length-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=i;j>=0;j--)
            {
                int sum = a[i] + a[j];
                if(set.contains(sum) && max<sum)
                   max=sum;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( findMaximumNumbers(new int[]{ 6, 10, 12, 34, 40, 16, 41, 47, 74 }));
        System.out.println( findMaximumNumbers(new int[]{ 2, 25, 35, 40, 42, 60 }));
    }
}
```

This algorithm takes O(n^2) time complexity. Does anyone have a better algorithm for this?

Comment: The above code works fine only when you have a sorted input. Your input doesnt looks sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: `j=i` is that correct? Assuming 20 was also in the list, could you do 10 + 10 = 20?

Comment: from a complexity point of view, you need to do `n * (n-1) / 2` additions (or `n^2`, if the two elements need not to be distinct). I do not think that you can do better than O(n^2). And no a sidenote: don't write `int a[]`, write `int[] a` (the brackets influence the type and should thus be written next to the type, not the variable name).

Comment: *FYI:* If you change method to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) `findMaximumNumbers(int... a)`, you don't need to create array `findMaximumNumbers(6, 10, 12, 34, 41, 16)`

Comment: say you have values 40, 47 and 74 in your list also.... your alg will hit 41+6=47 and return failing to find 40+34=74. also if you sort there is no need to check the last entry as any sum will be greater than any element in the list.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. For input `2, 25, 35, 40, 42, 60` it returns `42` (2 + 40), when the correct answer is `60` (25+35).

Comment: @Turing85 TGIF, my brain is celebrating the weekend already, apparently. Thanks for pointing out my fubar. Comment fixed.

Comment: Isn't the complexity O(n^2 log n) ?  Unless I'm mistaken, simply visiting each pair in the list is going to be O(n^2) so I doubt you will improve complexity much.

Comment: @BillK you mean because one has to "find" the sum? Hmm... may be =)

Comment: No, I think I'm wrong--a hash lookup is o(1) except in the worst cases, so your original n^2 is probably good..and I don't think you will get it better.

Comment: the sort is n log n then you add the searching n^2. and as pointed out earlier alg isn't right yet. can't terminate early have to store each sum where the sum exists in the list and keep going until all elements are processed. only way to term early is to know that all remaining sums will be less than current max or bigger than anything in the list.

Comment: I made some updates to the code! Although it still doesn't improve the time complexity

Comment: By the way, If I were asking this in an interview, the most important thing I'd be looking for is do they ask for clarifications/specifications--Should it handle a large list?  Zeros? Negative numbers?  How often/fast must it run?  How much of a time crunch am I under?--and using the specifications to adapt their approach.

Comment: For input 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, your codes return 6. But I think the answer is 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest I could come up with.  Since the list is sorted, you work backwards, attempting to find if any pair adds up to the maximum remaining in the array (the `i` loop).  It will short circuit as fast as possible, with the correct answer.  In the `j` loop, counting down stops when you reach a value less than half of the target (no use iterating remaining values that can't add up to the target).  But I am hopeful someone can do better.  The OP code will do `n*(n-1)/2` iterations, but this one will always do less, even when there is no solution.

```
public static int findMaximumNumbers(int a[])
{
    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
    for(int n:a) set.add(n);
    Arrays.sort(a);
    if (a[0] == 0)
        return a[a.length-1];
    for(int i=a.length-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        int j = i-1;
        int m = a[i] / 2;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > m) {
            if (set.contains(a[i]-a[j]))
                return a[i];
            j--;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This will fail when the input will be 
0 1

Comment: Corrected.  Thank you.  (I am assuming positive numbers only).  Question didn't say.

Comment: What if the input is 
0 1 2 3 10
The output must be 3, but your code will result into output 10

Comment: I don't understand the question then.  Any two elements are [0,10].

Comment: If its only about the positive number, it should work fine. But in case of negative number such as
-2 0
this should result into -2 instead of -1.

Comment: Agreed.  If the input should allow negative, I would revise the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are integers in the range 1 to M, then you can do this in O(Mlog(M)) by:

1. Computing a histogram of the values
2. Using the fast fourier transform to perform a convolution
3. searching for the biggest value present in the convolution

Example Python code:

```
import scipy.signal
import time

def hist(X):
    """Prepare a histogram of X"""
    h = [0]*(max(X)+1)
    for x in X:
        h[x] += 1
    return h

A = [6, 10, 12, 34, 41, 16]
H = hist(A)
R = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(H,H)
for x in sorted(A,reverse=True):
    if R[x] > 0.5:
        print x
        break
else:
    print 'No solutions'
```

The point is that the convolution of the histograms is the histogram of all possible sums of elements.

Of course, if you have 100 numbers with values in the range 1 to 10**100, then this would be less efficient than your O(n^2) algorithm so this is only useful if the values are limited.

Answer (score -1):

If you sort the array first, you can just check pair by pair in ascending order, adding two consecutive numbers and checking if it is contained in the array.

```
int myArray[];

Arrays.sort(myArray);

int a = -1, b, highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) 
{
    int sum = myArray[i] + myArray[i + 1];

    int startCheck = i + 1;
    while(myArray[startCheck] < sum && startCheck < myArray.length)
        startCheck++;

    if(myArray[startCheck] == sum && sum > highest)
    {
        a = i;
        b = i + 1;
        highest = sum;
    }
}

// Found 2 elements whose sum is on the array
if(a != -1)
{

}
```